# How to decide which function to call with JQuery and Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been working on single page application where users can run different processes. That would involve adding new records, updating existing records and deleting records in some situations. My question is what is the best way to handle this processes on the front end? I have tried to monitor how `Stack-overflow` works and how they handle this situations. Still can say 100% that I'm understanding if they use different `url` or they use submitted form data to decide which process should run on the back end. Here is small example:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
       <button type="button" name="new_record" id="new_record">New</button>
   </div>
</div>
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Status</th>
         <th>Edit</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>Active</td>
        <td class="text-center">
           <button class="record_edit">Edit</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

In HTML above you can see two different buttons `New` and `Edit`. I only showed one record in table for testing purpose. So this si situation where I'm wondering how to handle this in JQuery/JavaScript and Ajax. Here is example of my js code:

```
$('#frmSave').on('submit', submitFrm);
function submitFrm(e){
    var formData = frmObject.serialize();

    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'Components/Functions.cfc?method=saveData',
       data: formData,
       dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(obj){
       if(obj.STATUS === 200){
           // Successfully saved.
       }else{
           // Error!   
       }  
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
       alert('Error: '+errorThrown);
    });
}
```

You can see that I call one function for both cases New and Edit. On the back end I have two different processes. One it's for insert and other for update. Based on parameters passed from the user that will be decided on the back end. How ever I know that I can use `data-attributes` and append that value to my `formData` with `url` name and send to the server. Some people will say that is not reliable.My code on the back end will Insert or Update based on the submitted parameters in form data. I'm wondering what is a good way for this situation now days. How that is handled in professional manner? If anyone have a good example please let me know. One more thing, I would like to keep these two processes in the same function on the back end to prevent some code redundancy in my opinion.

Comment: Ive seen this done various ways. I have seen others store their code in a database and call it through ajax, and i have seen others load another js file based on the function and change the body to that page.  Perhaps you want to take more of a Angular approach

Comment: Where is the dom with id `frmSave`

Comment: @Tim Can you please provide example on how that should look like?

Comment: @brk I have not posted my entire form html for this purpose. `frmSave` is form id.

Comment: I would say, this approach is more than ok.
If you really want to make this professional, you can use a Framework.

Comment: @toffler In case I want to use framework and my current stack used on the from end (JavaScript/JQuery,Bootstrap 3) how that would look like? Any example or article would be helpful.

Comment: For my ColdFusion apps I will call my content with <cfinclude template='newcontent.cfm'>. On a form change or navigation, i will use a another cfinclude for that template that will replace the entire dom or just the body and will also have the javascript for that page. Without writing out a ton of code, it would be pretty hard to show you.

Comment: @espresso_coffee
https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1730-building-single-page-applications-using-jquery-and-coldfusion-with-ben-nadel-video-presentation.htm

Comment: @Tim I try to use minimum number of `.cfm` files on front end. All forms and html is in one `.cfm` file and I use bootstrap data-toggle to show hide elements on the screen.

Comment: Why not wrap it in a function with parameters? E.g. `function functionName(edit) { }` ?

Comment: @GavinThomas I'm not opposed to that option. I just wanted to hear if there is a better way or using parameter is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something as simple as

```
.done(function(obj){
       if(obj.STATUS === 200){
           // Successfully saved.
            $('#main').load("./newContent.cfm");
          }
```

So on success, it loads the newContent page.

Comment: In this situation user won't see data previously saved. They will get completely new blank form, correct?

Comment: You could change it and do different things based on your needs. this is just an example. so you could use .append() instead and load the newContent at the end of the div. The possibilities are endless.